# C++ Acess console application

Tags: c++, ms-access

connection to access is normal, the SQL query is executed, I get a SQL Success response. and I can't do it anymore. how to get data from sql query

```
int bdacess(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

    /* Connect to the database */
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (WCHAR*)szDSN, SQL_NTS, (WCHAR*)szConnStrOut, 255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {
        wprintf(L"Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n", szConnStrOut);

        /* Prepare SQL query */
        wprintf(L"SQL query:\n  %s\n", query);

        rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);
        rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS);
   
        /* Excecute the query */
        rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
        {
            wprintf(L"SQL Success\n");
        }
        else {
            wprintf(L"SQL Failed\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Couldn't connect to %s.\n", szDSN);
    }

    /* Disconnect and free up allocated handles */
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't get the result of sql execution itself

Comment: The result of the query should be in a specific data structure.

Comment: you need to use SQLFetch or SQLGetData to retrive the results of a query.